# Magento Admin: Unable to login admin, without any error it goes to index.php url and same with add to cart click

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting, phpmyadmin, magento-1.9

I'm into a big trouble today and looking for a immediate support.

I changed some Session Validation Setting to 'Yes' and I changed permanent Redirect 301 and till the time it was working fine.

but after some time after logout, when I tried to login again at admin panel, it was redirecting me to my website with /index.php. No error or any message.

And same happens when I try to 'Add Products to Cart' on my website. It's moving to Homepage.

I've been trying to fix it for the last  eight hours and tried all the available option on Google but nothing has worked out yet.

I hope somebody is having the solution for this problem.

Please help guys..

Thanks
Amit

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Magento session validation does not really provide any additional security for your customers. On the other hand, it can cause perfactly valid session to fail validations.

`REMOTE_ADDR` is just one example where valid session will fail validation. Validation will fail when user changes the network used to access the shop. This is especially dangerous for mobile users.

This could very well be the cause of your issues. I recommend disabling sesison validation.

Best of luck!

Comment: Well I have tried to disable it in " /files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php" file but It doesn't help at all. It shows 505 error after this. I'm following below: // session cookie params
    $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        // 'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        // 'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        // 'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );

Comment: Any other way to come from such situation... If It is not resolved I will have to work out again from scratch... you can check out my website i.e. http://www.yuvakart.com, its almost finishing line. Please help if you can...

Comment: If you check you cookies, you will see that your session ID changes each time you try to add product to cart. Session ID changes, almost certanly because validation fails.

Since you are no longer able to log in to admin panel, I recommend you create database  backup and than manually change those settings in `core_config_data`.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to mark correct answer. :)